# How to populate multiple labels with only one text box?

Tags: c#, logic

I am trying to populate one label after another using only one textbox. Right now it always populates label3, but not label4, what is wrong with the logic?

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Label3.Text == null)
    {
        Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else 
    {
        Label4.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are after, but `Label3.Text` might not be only `null` but empty too `""`. I am not sure how it behaves, but it's worth of testing.

Comment: You need to show the rest of the code for clarity, I only see 2 labels in your code.

Comment: why not use the `Controls Class` and use one Label.Text Property to set the text of all the TextBox controls on the form.. so if you have 100 text boxes you only need to write one foreach loop, check the `if(!IsNullOrEmpty(Label.Text){}` then from there use the foreach loop to check the type of control is TextBox.. then if true, assing that controls.Text property to the Label3.Text

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through all the labels on the form (you could also do this recursivley) and do something like this. You could also put in more checks if you only want to update certain labels.

```
foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(Label))
    {
        Label l = (Lablel)ctl;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(l.Text)) l.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic logic here.  See your problem in the comments.

```
if (Label3.Text == null)
{
    Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
else 'this will NEVER HAPPEN IF Label3.Text is NULL
{

    Label4.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Instead, do this

```
if (Label3.Text == null)
{
    Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}

if (Label4.Text == null)
{
    Label4.Text = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: @DJKRAZE That is very true, but if the author can't understand the basic logic error in their code, I don't think they'd be ready for more "advanced" constructs.

Comment: that's true too.. but learning something new means that the day has not been wasted..LOL

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for something like this:

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (StringIsNullOrEmpty(Label3.Text))
    {
        Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }

    if (StringIsNullOrEmpty(Label4.Text))
    {
        Label4.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

In your sample you have the Label4 assingment under the else statement, wich will only be executed case the if statement returns false (Label3.Text != null).